# Switching EF connection strings at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I know this question has been asked and answered a few times already, but every answer I have encountered has either been incomplete, overly vague or assumes more prerequisite knowledge than I have. I am seeking step-by-step instructions, in reasonably plain English, to swap out the database in my default connection string for a database name that will be looked up in a table. I keep coming across this snippet of code...

```
    public DFDBEntities(string connectionString)

        : base(connectionString)
    {

    }
```

...but no one really explains how, and where, to implement it. Assuming I have a class called "db" that represents my DataModel.EDMX model...

```
    private DataModel db = new DataModel();
```

...how would I change the connection string associated with that class to point to a different physical database (with identical data structure)?

Comment: Can you show us some code where you iniate the DBContect ?

Answer (score 1):

By using the default constructor you are basically saying *"I want to use the default connection string"* which is specified in the `web.config`.

The `DbContext` has a [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) which allows you override the default connection string, all you need to do is pass it in

```
db = new DataModel("MyConnectionStr");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
 private DataModel db = new DataModel(yourconnectionString);
```

Comment: I tried it and got a "MyProject.Models.DataModel does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments" error. I checked and it expects 0 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper class for connenction settings like

```
public class EntityConnectionStringHelper
    {
        public static string Build()
        {
            string serverName = "******";
            string databaseName = "****";
            string password = "****";
            string userid = "*****";
            string meta = "********";
            return EntityConnectionStringHelper.Build(serverName, databaseName, userid, password, meta);
        }
        public static string Build(string serverName, string databaseName, string userName, string password, string metaData)
        {
            // Specify the provider name, server and database.
            string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
            return EntityConnectionStringHelper.Build(providerName, serverName, databaseName, userName, password, metaData);
        }
        public static string Build(string providerName, string serverName, string databaseName, string userName, string password, string metaData)
        {
            // Initialize the connection string builder for the
            // underlying provider.
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            // Set the properties for the data source.
            sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
            sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
            sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
            sqlBuilder.UserID = userName;
            sqlBuilder.Password = password;

            // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
            string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

            // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

            //Set the provider name.
            entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

            // Set the provider-specific connection string.
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

            // Set the Metadata location.
            entityBuilder.Metadata = string.Format(@"res://*/{0}.csdl|res://*/{0}.ssdl|res://*/{0}.msl", metaData);

            return entityBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Than for your entity you can get intance with

```
DFDBEntities context = new DFDBEntities (EntityConnectionStringHelper.Build());
```